# MS Bot Framework : How to write tests for buttons?

Tags: botframework

I have a dialog that presents a list of options as buttons :

```
  bot.dialog('menu', [
        (session) => {
            builder.Prompts.choice(
                session, 
                'Your choices', 
                ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Exit'], 
                { 
                    listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button 
            });

        },
        (session, results) => {
            let input = _.get(results, 'response.entity', null) || _.get(session, 'message.text', null);
            switch (input) {
                default:
                    session.endDialog("Please chose from available options.");
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    session.send("You chose A");
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    session.beginDialog("You chose B");
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    session.beginDialog("You chose C");
                    break;
                case 'Exit':
                    session.endDialog("Thanks for using menu!");
                    break;
        }
    }]
    ).triggerAction({
        matches: /^(menu)$/i
    })
}
```

This works when I either press the button or enter the choice through the text input.

However, when I test the dialog through an automated test, it is not happy with the text input.

Here's the test :

```
describe('menuDialog', function (done) {
    this.timeout(50000);

    // Test case for menu
    it('should present a list of options', function (done) {
        var step = 0;
        var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector();
        var bot = universalBot(connector);

        // Register a dialog to test
        menuDialog(bot, builder);


        bot.on('send', function (message) {
            switch (++step) {
                case 1:
                    console.log(`Step : ${step}`);
                    assert(message.text == 'Your Choices');
                    connector.processMessage('A');
                    done()
                    break;
                case 2:
                    console.log("STEP : ", step)
                    assert(message.text == 'You Chose A');
                    done()
                    break;
           }
       });
        connector.processMessage('menu');
    });

});
```

The test fails and `message.text` at step 2 is :

```
Oops something went wrong and we need to start over.
```

How do I test for the buttons if not through `connector.processMessage()` ?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used Mocha, does `assert(message.text ==  'You Chose A);` need a closing `'`? i.e `asset(message.text == 'You Chose A');`

Are `Choices` and `Chose` supposed to be lowercase?

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a typo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your bot's dialog code inside the test block, so that the test can access it.

Here is a working version of your test intent:

```
// BEGIN buttons.test.js

var builder = require('botbuilder');
var assert = require('assert');

describe('menuDialog', function() {
    this.timeout(5000);
    // Test case for menu
    it('should present a list of options', function (done) {
        var step = 0;
        var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector();
        //var bot = universalBot(connector);
        var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

        bot.dialog('/', [
            (session) => {
                builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Your choices', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Exit'], {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});

            },
            (session, results) => {
                console.log('selected option: ' + results.response.entity);

                switch (results.response.entity) {
                    case 'A':
                        session.send("You picked A");
                        break;
                    case 'B':
                        session.beginDialog("You picked B");
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        session.beginDialog("You picked C");
                        break;
                    case 'Exit':
                        session.endDialog("You picked Exit");
                        break;
                    default:
                        session.endDialog("Please chose from available options.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        ]);

        bot.on('send', function (message) {
            switch (++step) {
                case 1:
                    console.log(`Step: ${step}`);
                    assert(message.text == 'Your choices');
                    connector.processMessage('A');
                    done();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    console.log(`Step: ${step}`);
                    assert(message.text == 'You picked A');
                    done();
                    break;
            }
        });
        connector.processMessage('start');
    });   
});

// END buttons.test.js
// to run: mocha buttons.test.js
```

Comment: It is doing so through menuDialog(bot, builder)